# ActionFilterAttribute on Controller vs action method

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, action-filter, actionfilterattribute

I have a `LoggingAttribute` which logs request and response in `OnActionExecuted` method:

```
public class LoggingAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuted(HttpActionExecutedContext httpContext)
    {
            //Logger.Log();
    }
}
```

There is another attribute for validating the request and return `BadRequest`. This return response from `OnActionExecuting` method:

```
public class ValidateModelAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        var modelState = actionContext.ModelState;
        if (!modelState.IsValid)
        {
            actionContext.Response = actionContext.Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, modelState);
        }
    }
}
```

Now, when I apply both these attributes on Action method, my `BadRequest`s are not being logged but when I apply `LoggingAttribute` on controller level and `ValidateModelAttribute` on action method, `BadRequest`s are getting logged (`OnActionExecuted` of `LoggingAttribute` getting called).

Can someone please explain this behaviour i.e. `OnActionExecuted` getting called even when action method is not being executed when attribute applied at controller.

Comment: are you getting break point on LoggingAttribute when you apply both attribute

Comment: If applying both on actionmethod - No. If LoggingAttribute at controller level and ValidateModetAttribute at action method - Yes.

Comment: have you tried with alter the sequence on action method?

Comment: Have you added any global filter?

Comment: @programtreasures just checked that it is dependent on the sequence. if I apply LoggingAttribute first, its OnActionExecuted is getting called. Please add the explanation in an answer.

Comment: hi, updated my answer , you can have look that will help ...

Answer (score 2):

You need to apply `LoggingAttribute` first on action method,

```
       [LoggingAttribute]
        [ValidateModelAttribute]        
        public IEnumerable<string> Get()
        {
            return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
        }
```

Comment: @programtreasures- sorry my bad , reverted my vote you are correct  and +1

Answer (score 1):

I tried you scenario like as below at my end

```
[HttpGet]
[ValidateModelAttribute]
[LoggingAttribute]
public void test()
{
   //throw new NotImplementedException("This method is not implemented");
}
```

With the same code as yours and I found same issue as you , your `LogginAttribute` not get called because you are setting repose for context in your `ValidateModelAttribute`, as request get response it returns immediately(because of this `actionContext.Response =` ) as request got response , and then it even doesnt call you method on which you applied attribute.

So solution for this part is you have to write `OnActionExecuting` which get called before your `Validationattribute OnActionExecuting` method, and your code will log as `OnActionExecuting` method of `LoggingAttribute` before you are returning response.

```
public class LoggingAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
   public override void OnActionExecuting
      (System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpActionContext actionContext)
        {
            //Logger.Log();
        }

   public override void OnActionExecuted(HttpActionExecutedContext httpContext)
        {
            //Logger.Log();
        }
}
```

and also **change order or attribute , reason for doing below is when `Response` is set then in that case it get return from that point only , so whatever filter is there in pipe line after than is not get called.**

```
[HttpGet]
[LoggingAttribute]
[ValidateModelAttribute]
public void test()
{
   //throw new NotImplementedException("This method is not implemented");
}
```

as suggested in below answer by @programtreasures

Comment: This attribute is not for exception logging, it is used to log all the requests of an API. Also, the answer is irrelevant to the question.

Comment: `OnActionExecuted` of `LoggingAttribute` will be called in the scenario you have mentioned. Please recheck it.

Comment: @PranayRana when Model is invalid and In `ValidateModelAttribute` setting response with bad request still it will call `OnActionExecuted` of `LoggingAttribute`, it will not return immediately when you set the response in `OnActionExecuting`. Correct this if I am wrong.